# Yii2 Multiple same models on one form

Tags: php, yii2

I am not sure if this is the correct way to use this framwork.

I have a table books ids, there is also containing a list of terms these can be added to e.g. name author etc.

I also have a table which contains the term data, so for example I have a term called 'Name' this has an id of 1, so in the term data table there would be termdataid, bookid, termid, value.

How can I represent these in a view?

At the moment I have created a new model called 'termholder' this allows me to hold the termid, bookid, value, termname.

```
$termfeilds= \app\models\TermField::findAll(['active'=>'1']);
$_arrayterms = [];

foreach($termfeilds as $termfeild){
    $_t = new \app\models\termholder();
    $_t->name = $termfeild->name;
    $_t->id = $termfeild->id;

    $_arrayterms[] = $_t;
}
   foreach($_arrayterms as $_arrayterm){
                   echo '<tr>
            <td>'. $_arrayterm->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$form->field($_arrayterm, 'value')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false).'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

This works fine however all the inputs have the same name so when it validates it teats them all as the same element.

I am going around this the correct way?

Comment: You want create - update - view ?? Show the related controller please .. and the complete view code...

Comment: Did you check http://demos.krajee.com/detail-view ?

Comment: Fantastic guys thanks for the help, I can just put the id in square brackets to differentiate the input name.